# How to import python modules in libreoffice snap

Tags: python, libreoffice-calc

I'm following the guide here:

https://help.libreoffice.org/6.3/en-US/text/sbasic/python/python_session.html?&DbPAR=WRITER&System=UNIX

I have a folder /snap/libreoffice/current/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python/Session, with a file inside: Session.py

and this import does not work:

```
import os,sys,time,stat
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")

CURR_path = home + "/snap/libreoffice/current/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python"
sys.path.insert(0, CURR_path )
from Session import Session
```

Anybody experience with adding python libraries to libreoffice snap?

Session.py:

```
import getpass, os, os.path, uno

class Session():
    @staticmethod
    def substitute(var_name):
        ctx = uno.getComponentContext()
        ps = ctx.getServiceManager().createInstanceWithContext(
            'com.sun.star.util.PathSubstitution', ctx)
        return ps.getSubstituteVariableValue(var_name)
    @staticmethod
    def Share():
        inst = uno.fileUrlToSystemPath(Session.substitute("$(prog)"))
        return os.path.normpath(inst.replace('program', "Share"))
    @staticmethod
    def SharedScripts():
        return ''.join([Session.Share(), os.sep, "Scripts"])
    @staticmethod
    def SharedPythonScripts():
        return ''.join([Session.SharedScripts(), os.sep, 'python'])
    @property  # alternative to '$(username)' variable
    def UserName(self): return getpass.getuser()
    @property
    def UserProfile(self):
        return uno.fileUrlToSystemPath(Session.substitute("$(user)"))
    @property
    def UserScripts(self):
        return ''.join([self.UserProfile, os.sep, 'Scripts'])
    @property
    def UserPythonScripts(self):
        return ''.join([self.UserScripts, os.sep, "python"])
```

Comment: `/snap` is not the same as `~/snap`. If that is the location and your code then presumably it would not find the file. Also, try putting `Session.py` in a pythonpath subdirectory, for example `Scripts/python/pythonpath`. LibreOffice adds pythonpath to the system path for importing.

Comment: The path was right; adding the pythonpath folder did the trick! thanks @JimK